# Can sunlight and its heat create a caustic or toxic substance from coconut oil on human skin?

Tags: biochemistry, safety, electromagnetic-radiation

I heard that story quite often, if it's true, how does it work?

Notice that I’m not talking about using coconut oil as a sunscreen (it’s another topic) but about the action of the sun on the oil and its impact on the human skin: will coconut oil degrade into something toxic under the sun, if so why?

And also, does the same degradation mechanisms applied for other oils (such as olive oil).

Comment: I'm not sure medical related questions are allowed on this forum. I think you would be better served by either consulting a legally certified physician or by checking medical information sites online.

Comment: I do not understand why this was closed: "I’m not talking about using coconut oil as a sunscreen" makes it pretty clear that the interest  lies in reactions due to UV, not the medical apects.

Comment: I also believe it can be answered from a objective chemistry point of view, hence I recommend reopening. However, I am not yet overruling the vote of the community.

Comment: @shre_sudh_97 There is a misunderstanding : the question is not about health but chemistry. And I did not find anything on the web about this chemical mechanism (if it occurs). Please reopen the question.

Comment: @Lisa "Is there a list somewhere of safe to use oil in the sun?". This question makes me consider this to be a personal medical question.

Comment: @shre_sudh_97 I agree, the "safe" could be understood in that way, so I removed it. The question concern the chemical mechanism about this skin-sun-UV-oil interaction. So could you please reopen the question?

Comment: @Lisa Yes. Now the question is about chemistry than about health. I'm not sure how I can reopen it. It was closed by moderators. I'll surely upvote it now as it is a valid question.

Comment: @Joel The question has been edited. My comment was for the previous wording of the question.